# Regex/Unix Tool to insert a new line before the beginning of every function definition in a C++ file

Tags: c++, regex

**Edit:**

```
indent -bap foo.cpp
```

**works**

Is there any easy way to insert a new line or insert a text before the beginning of every function definition in C++ file?

```
int main() {
  return 0;
}
void foo() {
}
```

becomes

```
int main() {
  return 0;
}

void foo() {
}
```

Comment: ... It's hard enough getting regex to parse HTML, and now you want it to do C as well??

Comment: I know it's hard. I was looking more on the lines of a tool that does it. Changed the question to make it more clear.

Comment: you can do "indent -bap foo.cpp". This works!

Comment: Since you found the solution yourself, you can post it as an answer and accept that answer, rather than editing the question.

Answer (score 0):

In Perl:

```
while(my $line = <>)
{
  $line =~ s/^\}[ \t]*$/}\n/;
  print $line;
}
```

That will also insert something at the end of every namespace (but not struct or class since they have a semi-colon at the end).  You could probably get more clever to avoid that, but I suspect that may be overkill.

That also notably will not catch functions that are defined inline in a class declaration.  I'm not sure if that's a case that's important in your case.

Comment: I am finding the indent program in Unix pretty useful today. See my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing C++ source code with regexp is guaranteed to fail for some cases (which might not occur 
for you depending on your source code/coding style), so some kind of parsing is always a better strategy.

I would have started by looking into the source code of cproto to see if it simply could be changed to add a blank line when it finds a function.

Update: [cproto](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cproto/) does not handle C++, but [genproto](http://freequaos.host.sk/genproto/) does.